# Laptop shuts down directly after boot due to wrong thermal sensor reading

Tags: kernel, shutdown, 20.10, temperature

A few seconds after I unlock the boot partition (luks), my laptop just poweres off.
In the log I found:

```
kernel: thermal thermal_zone2: critical temperature reached (238 C), shutting down
```

This reading is definetly wrong, Windows reads a temperature of about 60°C.
Can I somehow adjust the formula of the readings?

Kernel 5.8.0-43, same with 5.8.0-41, but not with 5.4.*.

Comment: Please try the current [Ubuntu mainline PPA](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D) kernel, [5.11](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.11/), just as test to determine if the problem has been fixed upstream. If not it should be bug reported, but isolating it might require a kernel bisection. what processor make and model?

Answer (score 0):

A wrong reading of 238 degrees would certainly be an issue. You'll need to update the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line in your `/etc/default/grub` file to include the `thermal.nocrt=1` flag so that it looks something like:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash thermal.nocrt=1"
```

Then update with:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then reboot. That should resolve the error message. Once that's done, you'll need to figure out which temperature sensor package is either installed wrong or not reporting the information correctly.